# Interop.Word Find and Hyperlink that word

Tags: c#, hyperlink, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to create a program which searches in a Word doc for a certain word and adds a hyperlink to that word.

I can do the code to search for the word (using a `FindandReplace`), and can work out how to add a hyperlink to a word doc, but I cannot work out how to hyperlink the word I searched for.  I think its because I need to define the word I searched for as a Range.

My code so far is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor;

...

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// open word doc  
object fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
applicationWord.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc =     applicationWord.Documents.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
//using FindAndReplace
        Word.Find fnd = applicationWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find;
        fnd.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Forward = true;
        fnd.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
        fnd.MatchCase = true;
        fnd.MatchWholeWord = true;
        fnd.Text = "Qwe";
        fnd.Replacement.Text = "Qwe";
        fnd.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

        Word.Hyperlinks hyp = doc.Hyperlinks;
        object myRange = applicationWord.Selection.Range;
        object linkAddr = textBox1.Text;
        object linkSubAddr = textBox2.Text;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink myLink = hyp.Add(myRange, ref linkAddr, ref linkSubAddr);
    }
```

I just can't get the hyperlink to be applied to the Word I searched for

Comment: You should include the code you currently have as it would help tailor answers

Comment: Thanks, I shall add it to the post

Comment: You should use a simple search, rather than replace, then process the range that it finds for you