# How to Append Clickable Hyperlink to Comment in Word

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented a hyperlink interface; when the user selects text in the document and then clicks a button from my Word Add-in, there is a comment box that is pre-filled with text added to this selection.

However, I want to include a hyperlink that is clickable to bring the user to a Google Doc and this link should be at the end of the comment box. This is what I have tried so far:

```
Hyperlink link = new Link();
link.Address = (String) oAddress;
link.SubAddress = (String) oSubAddress;
link.TextToDisplay = "more";
selection.Comments.Add(rng2, comment + link)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create a collection of `Hyperlinks` from your current document, then add your hyperlink to it.

Below code should highlight everything inside your comment.

```
// Select the element you want to apply the hyperlink to - you will have to use the Find method
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range currentRange = myDoc.Comments[0].Range

if (currentRange != null)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink hp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink)
    // This line is what you are missing
    currentRange.Hyperlinks.Add(currentRange, "http://www.microsoft.com");

}
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665770/5209435.

You can use the above as a base before using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx) method to narrow to find the text that you want to hyperlink and just apply it to the selected text. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556955/interop-word-find-and-hyperlink-that-word).